# RegExp : How to replace the second occurrence using object?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function convertHTML(str) {
  var objA={'&':'&​amp;','<':'&​lt;','>':'&​gt;','\'':'&​apos;','"':'\&​quot;'}
  var matchStr = str.match(/([&|''|""|>|<])/g)
  var matchStr1=''
  for(var i=0; i<matchStr.length; ++i){

     matchStr1 = str.replace(matchStr[i], objA[matchStr[i]])

  }
  return matchStr1;
}

console.log(convertHTML("Hamburgers < Pizza < Tacos "));
```

Output i'm getting is `Hamburgers &â€‹lt; Pizza < Tacos`. I want `Hamburgers &â€‹lt; Pizza &â€‹lt; Tacos`. So is it possible to replace the second occurrence using this code with some changes ?.

Comment: `[&|''|""|>|<]` is not valid - you can't alternate inside a character class

Comment: Interesting, but not getting the result you are expecting and for what? May be there is some more easy way

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use following approach.

```js
var objMap = {             // ===> object with specified keys
  '&': '&​amp;',            // ===> that have to be replaced
  '<': '&​lt;',             // ===> with their corresponding values
  '>': '&​gt;',
  '\'': '&​apos;',
  '"': '\&​quot;'
}

function convertHTML(str) {
  var res = str.replace(/[&<>\\"]/g, match => objMap[match]);
  return res;
}

console.log(convertHTML("Hamburgers < Pizza < Tacos "));
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in line:

```
matchStr1 = str.replace(matchStr[i], objA[matchStr[i]])
```

In each iteration "str" is always the same.

Your code fixed:

```
function convertHTML(str) {
  var objA={'&':'&​amp;','<':'&​lt;','>':'&​gt;','\'':'&​apos;','"':'\&​quot;'}
  var matchStr = str.match(/([&|''|""|>|<])/g);
  for(var i=0; i<matchStr.length; ++i){
     str = str.replace(matchStr[i], objA[matchStr[i]])
  }
  return str;
}
console.log(convertHTML("Hamburgers < Pizza < Tacos "));
```